# PHP create array from two other arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Thats my first post here, so first of all, sorry for mistakes.
I Cant solve some problem.
I have to create an array from two other arrays :

Array#1:

```
$a = array(5, 2, 3);
```

Array#2:

```
$b = array(0 => array(
                      'key1' => '2',
                      'key2' => 'content2'),
          (1 => array(
                      'key1' => '3',
                      'key2' => 'content3'),
          (2 => array( 
                      'key1' => '5', 
                      'key2' => 'content1');
```

My output array have to be sth like that:

```
$output = array(0 => array(
                      'key1' => '5',
                      'key2' => 'content1'),
          (1 => array(
                      'key1' => '2',
                      'key2' => 'content2'),
          (2 => array( 
                      'key1' => '3', 
                      'key2' => 'content3');
```

And i totally dont know how to solve my problem. No idea what to do. I tried almost everything. Any help? How to start (again)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via `foreach` loops:

```
$a = array(5, 2, 3);
$b = array(
    array('key1' => '2', 'key2' => 'content2'),
    array('key1' => '3','key2' => 'content3'),
    array('key1' => '5', 'key2' => 'content1')
);

$new = array();
foreach($a as $key) {
    foreach($b as $item) {
        if($item['key1'] == $key) {
            array_push($new, $item);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/296266)

---

**Note**

Please attempt the question before posting your code.

What you should be looking at is [PHP's array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) and creating a solution to match what you require. Best to look at [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)/[`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Answer (score 1):

**try a loop to create the new table**

```
$x = array(5, 2, 3);
$y = array(0 => array(
                      'key1' => '2',
                      'key2' => 'content2'),
          1 => array(
                      'key1' => '3',
                      'key2' => 'content3'),
          2 => array( 
                      'key1' => '5', 
                      'key2' => 'content1'));

$new_arr = array();

foreach ($x as $xvalue) {
foreach ($y as $yvalue) {
   if($yvalue['key1']==$xvalue) {
$new_arr[] = $yvalue;
}
}
}
var_dump($new_arr);
```

**sandbox**

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7cd210a0282279af9dfe97395ea8eba04d9eb137